# What flags are used to compile debian stable packages?

Tags: security, compiling, compiler

Ubuntu wiki states that its packages are compiled with secure flags and secure kernel options.  I cannot find this information about debian.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CompilerFlags

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Debian has anything exactly comparable to this. Here is [Chapter 10 of Debian Policy: Files](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html), which has some information about compile time flags. Note the sentence

> It is up to the package maintainer to
>   decide what compilation options are
>   best for the package.

In short, Debian doesn't tell its developers what flags to use.